# INSERT INTO Google Fusion Tables Using Python

Tags: python, google-fusion-tables

I need some assistance writing to Google Fusion Tables using python. I can read them ok, but that is a GET and I think I need a POST.

Below is my closest attempt, but I am stuck.

```
import httplib, urllib
query = 'sql=INSERT INTO 3686128 (column1, column2) VALUES (12,16)'
params = urllib.urlencode({'sql': query})
##headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept": "text/plain"}
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("https:\\www.google.com\fusiontables\api\query", 80)
conn.request("POST", "", params)#, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason
data = response.read()
print data
conn.close()
```

Thanks!

-Karl

Answer (score 0):

You need to login in order to do inserts or updates.
There is a nice python library which handles most of this for you at [Google Code fusion-table-client-python](http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables-client-python/) which includes [sample code](http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables-client-python/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fsamples).

Comment: Even on public tables? I know how to do the login and will try that, but in this case I do not think it is necessary, nor do I think that is the problem in this case.

Comment: Yes. Even on public tables.  I don't think there is an option to grant write access to the world.

Comment: The link that you provide is of an old API that will not work. Any Python example related to the new 1.0 API is non existing. Please help.